# Mysql how to sum column with previous column sum and group by different column

Tags: mysql

I have a unusual situation where I need to display a few columns in as a result and sum a column (units) from the the previous result in a column.
But only while the stock value code is the same value, otherwise restart the sum.

I have written this so far

```
    SELECT
    trades.tx_date,
    trades.stock_code,
    trades.currency,
    trades.units,
    ( @sum := @sum + units ) AS unit_bal_total 
FROM
    trades
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @sum := 0 ) params 
ORDER BY
    trades.stock_code ASC,
    trades.tx_date ASC
```

this image on the right is what I am trying to achieve and on the left is what I get
and help would be appreciated
[image]

I have uploaded the query and database in https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uWGzytY3fyfT6t8rTiK3Ny/1
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is cumulative sum. Use window function for this.

Comment: I don't think MySQL 5.7.33 has window function support? only version 8 and we dont run that unfortunatly

Comment: You have not provided the version firstly, so I give you the solution for actual version. For your version use one more UDV and store `stock_code` of the previous row in it. How many rows (approximately) does the table contains?

Comment: 2000 - 2400 rows at moment but will increase slowly with time.  I am quite a armature really I dont know how I even got this far with this query spent the last 5 hours working on it.... What is a UDV?

Comment: For this tiny table you may use a query with 2 table copies.

Comment: From the other side - your data contains rows which have the same `(stock_code, tx_date)` value. These rows ordering is not definite with current ORDER BY expression, they may swap their relative position at any time, this will change the query output which is hence not deterministic. You shouls find additional criteria which will set definite rows ordering (maybe your table have some autoincremented `id`?).

Comment: @Thomas - do you have some sample data. you can copy it to http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: yes i have uploaded the sample data now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try a query like this:

```
SELECT tx_date
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX(@old:=IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@old,";",1) = stock_code, CONCAT(stock_code,";0"), CONCAT(stock_code,";1")),";",1) AS stock_code
        , units
        , IF ( SUBSTRING_INDEX(@old,";",-1) = 1 , @sum := units, @sum := @sum + units) AS units_bal_total
FROM trades
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @old:="" , @sum := 0) AS params
ORDER BY
    trades.stock_code ASC,
    trades.tx_date ASC ;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * from trades;
+----+------------+------------+-------+
| id | tx_date    | stock_code | units |
+----+------------+------------+-------+
|  1 | 2020-11-09 | A2M        |   100 |
|  2 | 2020-11-11 | A2M        |   -50 |
|  3 | 2020-11-12 | AAA        |   500 |
|  4 | 2020-11-13 | AAA        |    50 |
|  5 | 2020-11-14 | AAA        |  -100 |
|  6 | 2020-11-15 | ABC        |   999 |
+----+------------+------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT tx_date
    ->   , SUBSTRING_INDEX(@old:=IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@old,";",1) = stock_code, CONCAT(stock_code,";0"), CONCAT(stock_code,";1")),";",1) AS stock_code
    ->   , units
    ->   , IF ( SUBSTRING_INDEX(@old,";",-1) = 1 , @sum := units, @sum := @sum + units) AS units_bal_total
    -> FROM trades
    -> CROSS JOIN (SELECT @old:="" , @sum := 0) AS params
    -> ORDER BY
    ->     trades.stock_code ASC,
    ->     trades.tx_date ASC ;
+------------+------------+-------+-----------------+
| tx_date    | stock_code | units | units_bal_total |
+------------+------------+-------+-----------------+
| 2020-11-09 | A2M        |   100 |             100 |
| 2020-11-11 | A2M        |   -50 |              50 |
| 2020-11-12 | AAA        |   500 |             500 |
| 2020-11-13 | AAA        |    50 |             550 |
| 2020-11-14 | AAA        |  -100 |             450 |
| 2020-11-15 | ABC        |   999 |             999 |
+------------+------------+-------+-----------------+
6 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Comment: I have uploaded the data to DBFIDDLE  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cX22QVVNYTu5oevsyjhDh8/1

I think the date orders is off in the live example